# What is the idiomatic way to work with inheritance from javascript?

Tags: purescript

For example javascript library has this hierarchy

```
class Base
class Foo:Base
class Bar:Base
```

and this function

```
calc(x:Base) : Int
calc(new Bar())
```

How do you write this function in PureScript?

```
foreign import calc :: ??? -> Int
```

Comment: Are you using the FFI with that JavaScript class hierarchy or do you want to also convert the class hierarchy to PureScript?

Comment: I want to be able to create class instances from PureScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on what do you want to do with these classes. I would do something like this:

```
-- purs file
foreign import data Base :: * 
foreign import data Foo :: * 
foreign import data Bar :: * 

fooToBase :: Foo -> Base 
fooToBase = unsafeCoerce 

barToBase :: Bar -> Base 
barToBase = unsafeCoerce 

foreign import newFoo :: forall e. Eff e Foo 
foreign import newBar :: forall e. Eff e Bar 
-- works with all ancestors
foreign import calc :: Base -> Eff e Unit 
-- works only with Foos
foreign import fooMethod :: String -> Foo -> Eff e Int

-- using
main = do 
  foo <- newFoo
  bar <- newBar
  calc $ fooToBase foo
  calc $ barToBase bar
  fooMethod "test" foo 


-- js file 
exports.newFoo = function() { return new Foo(); }; 
exports.newBar = function() { return new Bar(); };
exports.calc = function(o) {
  return function() {
    return o.calc();
  };
};
exports.fooMethod = function(str) {
  return function(o) {
    return function() {
      return o.fooMethod();
    };
  };
};
```

Everything here should live in `Eff` probably, because making new instances changes global state.